# Pagination is not working and no error messgage

Tags: liferay-6

There is no error in the file but the below code is not working after i deploy please check the code once and help me. The table is "Library" and the columns are "title" and "author".   **code in view.jsp is as shown below**

```
           <%   List<Library> list = LibraryLocalServiceUtil.getLibraries(-1, -1); %>
                 <liferay-ui:search-container delta="5" emptyResultsMessage="No Books Available">
                  <liferay-ui:search-container-results results="<%= ListUtil .subList(list, searchContainer.getStart(),searchContainer.getEnd()) %>" total="<%= list.size() %>" />
                  <liferay-ui:search-container-row
                  className="com.liferay.pagi.model.Library"
                   modelVar="aLibrary">
                  <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="title" />
                  <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="author" />
                  </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
                  <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
                  </liferay-ui:search-container>
        You will get all book titles and author names are show into the table.

        Give a link back to the main page.

                   <a href="<portlet:renderURL/>">&laquo; Go Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is working portlet just download and compare with your code..
I guest your list may be size 0 or empty. check it

```
List<Library> list = LibraryLocalServiceUtil.getLibraries(0,LibraryLocalServiceUtil.getCount());
```

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/03/liferay-search-container-with-curd.html
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/6.2.x/portlets/sample-ui-search-container-taglib-portlet